# How do I find the href attribute within each class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I'm trying to create an application whereas it runs through a web page and finds an href attribute, but for now I would like to find the href attribute, and alert my of the link.

I am new to JQuery, but I have tried to run the following via Fiddle, but I cannot seem to get it running:

```js
   $('soundTitle__tag sc-tag sc-tag-small').on("click", function() {
      var self = $(this);
      var link = self.find("a").attr('href');
      alert(link);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-redirect">
      <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
        <a class="soundTitle__tag sc-tag sc-tag-small" href="/home">1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
        <a class="soundTitle__tag sc-tag sc-tag-small" href="/home">2</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `$('.soundTitle.sc-tag.sc-tag-small')` missing `.` also no space between space between means child

Comment: Your selector searches for elements not classes

Comment: and self is already a tag. So you don't find ("a") inside it

Comment: as a side note: You might want to use [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) inside the click handler depending on what you want to do

Comment: @TreeNguyen meant _is already the "a" tag itself_

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments guys, unbelievable help. I've got it working now! Can't wait to delve into j query a lot more.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="link-redirect">
  <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
    <a class="soundTitle__tag sc-tag sc-tag-small" href="/home"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
    <a class="soundTitle__tag sc-tag sc-tag-small" href="/home"></a>
  </div>
```

when you click on **soundTitle__tagContainer** it will find the nearest anchor tag

```
 $('.soundTitle__tagContainer').on("click", function() {
      var self = $(this);
      var link = self.find("a").attr('href');
      alert(link);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.soundTitle__tag.sc-tag.sc-tag-small')`   write like this if your selector is anchor tag with three class.Or just wirte  `$('.soundTitle__tag')`.Use `.className` for selecting an element with class

`event.preventDefault();` Use this for perventing the default behaviour of the anchor tag.This will prevent a link from following the URL

```js
$('.soundTitle__tag.sc-tag.sc-tag-small').on("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var self = $(this); 
      var link = self.attr('href');
      alert(link);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-redirect">
      <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
        <a class="soundTitle__tag sc-tag sc-tag-small" href="/home">Link-1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
        <a class="soundTitle__tag sc-tag sc-tag-small" href="/home">Link-2</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.soundTitle__tag.sc-tag.sc-tag-small').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(link);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-redirect">
  <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
    <a class="soundTitle__tag sc-tag sc-tag-small" href="/home">link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
    <a class="soundTitle__tag sc-tag sc-tag-small" href="/home">link 2</a>
  </div>
```

As some people pointed out, *this* is going to be the link in the click handler. You also probably don't need such a verbose selector, as it creates tighter coupling between your scripts and DOM, but I left it intact (with the addition of the class selectors) for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.link-redirect a').each(function () {
  var $href = $(this).attr('href');
  if ($(this).is([href="/home"]) {
    alert($href);
  }
});
```

Check this one :) It could help you.

If doesn't work just change if statement to:

```
$href
```

without any is, has blablabla. Give answer if works.